# in SQL, best way to join first and last instance of child table without NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

in PostgreSQL, have `issue` table and child `issue_step` table - an issue contains one or more steps.

the view `issue_v` pulls things from the issue and the first and last step: `author` and `from_ts` are pulled from the first step, while `status` and `thru_ts` are pulled from the last step.

#### the tables

```
create table if not exists seeplai.issue(
  isu_id      serial        primary key,
  subject       varchar(240)
);
create table if not exists seeplai.issue_step(
  stp_id      serial        primary key,
  isu_id      int           not null references seeplai.issue on delete cascade,
  status      varchar(12)   default 'open',
  stp_ts      timestamp(0)  default current_timestamp,
  author      varchar(40),
  notes       text
);
```

#### the view

```
create view seeplai.issue_v as
select isu.*,
      first.stp_ts as from_ts,
      first.author as author,
      first.notes as notes,
      last.stp_ts as thru_ts,
      last.status as status
from  seeplai.issue isu
join  seeplai.issue_step first on( first.isu_id = isu.isu_id and not exists(
      select 1 from seeplai.issue_step where isu_id=isu.isu_id and stp_id>first.stp_id ) )
join  seeplai.issue_step last on( last.isu_id = isu.isu_id and not exists(
        select 1 from seeplai.issue_step where isu_id=isu.isu_id and stp_id<last.stp_id    ) );
```

note1: `issue_step.stp_id` is guaranteed to be chronologically sequential, so using it instead of `stp_ts` because it's already indexed

this works, but ugly as sin, and cannot be the most efficient query in the world.

Answer (score 2):

In this code, I use a sub-query to find the first and last step IDs, and then join to the two instances of the step table by using those found values.

```
SELECT  ISU.*
        ,S1.STP_TS AS FROM_TS
        ,S1.AUTHOR AS AUTHOR
        ,S1.NOTES AS NOTES
        ,S2.STP_TS AS THRU_TS
        ,S2.STATUS AS STATUS
FROM    SEEPLAI.ISSUE ISU
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT  ISU_ID
            ,MIN(STP_ID) AS MIN_ID
            ,MAX(STP_ID AS MAX_ID
    FROM    SEEPLAI.ISSUE_STEP
    GROUP BY
            ISU_ID
    ) SQ
ON  SQ.ISU_ID = ISU.ISU.ID
INNER JOIN
        SEEPLAI.ISSUE_STEP S1
ON      S1.STP_ID = SQ.MIN_ID
INNER JOIN
        SEEPLAI.ISSUE_STEP S2
ON      S2.STP_ID = SQ.MAX_ID
```

Note: you really shouldn't be using a select * in a view. It is much better practice to list out all the fields that you need in the view explicitly

Comment: 1. you view works, thanks.  it's faster than mine, but uglier.  not the holy grail.  2. I have heard several times about not using the "\*" in a view, but have never seen proof of the claim.  in postgres the view is compiled when it's declared, so I don't see how the "\*" effects performance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using window functions?

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html

A starting point:

```
select steps.*,
       first_value(steps.stp_id) over w as first_id,
       last_value(steps.stp_id) over w as last_id
from issue_step steps
window w as (partition by steps.isu_id order by steps.stp_id)
```

Btw, if you know the IDs in advance, you'll much be better off getting details in a separate query. (Trying to fetch everything in one go will just yield sucky plans due to subqueries or joins on aggregates, which will result in inefficiently considering/joining the entire tables together.)

Comment: 1. yes, I had _considered_ using window functions, but was dependent on a kickstart as to how to do it. Will study and post again.  2. regarding "getting details in a separate query", had thought that the cost of node->node.pg->pg->node.pg->node was costly enough to try to pack all the info into one query.

Comment: The costliest query you can get is something like: `select ... from (select issue.* from issue where ...) i join (select step.* from step where ... group by ...) s on ... where ...`, or its variation using subqueries -- which you're basically doing atm. The reason is, it's virtually guaranteed to join two entire tables together in a way or another, even if you only need a handful of rows in the end.

Comment: What you'll want in practice, I think, is something like `select step.* from step where isu_id in (...) having stp_id = first_value(stp_id) over w or stp_id = last_value(stp_id) over w window w as (...)`. The latter will yield two rows per appropriate `isu_id` without joins, using an index on `isu_id` or `(isu_id, stp_id)` to go straight for the results.

Comment: Lastly, note that using a view pretty much guarantees that you'll end up in the costly scenario no matter which convoluted variation of the query you decide to pick, because (in my experience anyway) the planner won't reliably re-inject the `where isu_id in (...)` where it belongs for an optimal plan.

Comment: agree costly queries outrun connection costs - over 30 years I've done more than my share of Cartesian products - but this view should be well behaved - have provided a simple min/max `view` as answer - plans quite nicely.  (in the past I have used triggers to keep `first` and `last` in the parent record, but in my current opinion this is usually pretty stupid.)

Comment: Keeping the first and last ID in the parent record is by no means stupid imho. On the contrary, it's your only reasonable option if you plan to create a view that is lightweight.

Comment: OK, after dicking around views waaay too long, went back to triggers which I can do in my sleep - now issue constantly has the first and last stp_id for joins.  although I am really good at this approach, and although it's really fast, it _still_ feels wrong in a normalized sort of way.